# Convention-driven configuration for WCF (server-side)

Tags: wcf, convention-over-configur

Just started on a new project and opened up a 1600 line `web.config` file for a WCF project, where 90% of the services are configured identically (hmfph).

I like a project to be easy to manage, with as few redundant lines of code as possible. So my question is whether or not it is possible to configure multiple WCF service by using convention-driven configuration instead.

Kind of like Fluent NHibernate Automapper with the possibility to create overrides when needed (like custom endpoints etc). Any thoughts?

/Jasper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF in .NET 4 has a lots of convention-based configuration - as long as you don't start specifying your own stuff, each service defined in your `web.config` will get a default endpoint for each of the base addresses defined in your `web.config` - that alone can cut out 50-80% of your config.

Furthermore, you can define default behaviors, e.g. for your services; things like *always expose metadata and make it available from HTTP* and so forth can be defined once, as a "template" behavior and will be applied to all service entries without further ado.

Check out all the details of what's new in WCF 4 and how to make use of the convention-driven configuration ("no config WCF") here: [A Developer's Introduction to WCF 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx)

Comment: Thanks - I'll look into WCF 4.0 features - we're still on .NET v3.5, but an upgrade is in the pipeline.